Problem with running Slurm
I'm trying to run a script that is using Slurm at the moment, but as I have no experience using it, I feel a bit lost.
I have a VM running Ubuntu LTS, and I'm following a Script that calls for:
sbatch --array=1-$nSamples%8 AMFseqTrimParallel.sh

After installing "Slurm" I still get the error:

/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf: No such file or directory, retrying in 1sec up to 60sec

It feels like I'm should not be using Slurm this way, but I am not sure, could someone make things clear for me, please?

What Ubuntu product & release; you mention an LTS but not which of the LTS releases you're using, and if desktop/server/flavor.
